# Why can I not use the onClick event handler to draw shapes onto a form in lazarus?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

My event handler is as follows:

```
procedure TfrmCanvasMethods.btnShapesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Canvas.Rectangle(40, 40, 400, 200);
    Canvas.Rectangle(80, 80, 360, 160);
    Canvas.Ellipse(150, 50, 290, 190);
    Canvas.Ellipse(100, 100, 340, 140);
end;
```

I am using Mac OS X

Comment: Drawing surface does not persist. Draw in response to paint events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read fundamentals about graphic windowing systems. Be it Windows, MacOS or UNIX X Window.

Almost universally that is not the application who decides when, what and where to draw. It is Operating System that decides so and asks the application when to do it. All an application can do - is to *invalidate* some part of its window - that is to *inform* the OS that some part of the window is no more valid, and then wait until the OS would want that part repainted (maybe it would be never, if the *invalidated* window got minimized or covered by another window) and then - and only then - do the drawing.

So how can you do it?

**Method 1**: resources-savvy and close to real OS workflow.

You put a `TPaintbox` over your whole `form`.

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPaintBox
- http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/extctrls/tpaintbox.html

You keep your rectangles and circles as non-visible records or classes inside your form's variables. When those figures are changed (example: you added yet another rectangle, or you increased some circle diameter) you call `MyForm.MyPaintBox.Invalidate` to inform the operating system that the image of that painboxt is no more valid. When OS would consider it is timely to refresh the image, it would call `MyForm.MyPaintBox.OnPaint` event and in that event you would make your calls like `MyPaintBox.Canvas.Rectangle(40, 40, 400, 200);`. Notice - you would repaint the paintbox's canvas, not the form's one!

```
procedure TfrmCanvasMethods.btnShapesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyPaintBox.Invalidate();  
end;

procedure TfrmCanvasMethods.MyPaintBoxPaint(Sender: TObject);
var Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  Canvas := MyPaintbox.Canvas;

    Canvas.Rectangle(40, 40, 400, 200);
    Canvas.Rectangle(80, 80, 360, 160);
    Canvas.Ellipse(150, 50, 290, 190);
    Canvas.Ellipse(100, 100, 340, 140);
end;
```

**Method 2**: lazy and resources-bloating

You put a `TImage` over your whole `form`.

- http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/extctrls/timage.html

That image would have the implicit bitmap having any picture you would like. More so, it would track your drawing of that picture and would automagically call `Invalidate` and would automagically handle OS's repaint requests.

```
procedure TfrmCanvasMethods.btnShapesClick(Sender: TObject);
var Canvas: TCanvas;
begin
  MyImage.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize( MyImage.ClientWidth, MyImage.ClientHeight );

  Canvas := MyImage.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas;

    Canvas.Rectangle(40, 40, 400, 200);
    Canvas.Rectangle(80, 80, 360, 160);
    Canvas.Ellipse(150, 50, 290, 190);
    Canvas.Ellipse(100, 100, 340, 140);
end;
```

The price however would be that you would allocate maybe as much as few megabytes of memory for nothing more than keeping your picture for those relatively rare cases when OS would need to refresh the picture of your form.